# Session timeout during call AJAX in codeigniter 4

Tags: ajax, codeigniter-4

When we are calling function in controller without AJAX and session timeout, codeigniter will redirect us to login page (for example). But if we call function in controller via AJAX, it will return error.

So we need to always check session manually in every function on controller?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what [Filters](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/filters.html) are for. Create a Filter that checks authorization however you need and apply that Filter to the required URIs.

You can even see if the request is AJAX in order to return a specific code; in your Javascript, your AJAX requests can specifically look for that code and then redirect to that login page if necessary.

```
  public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null){
    //However you check for your auth
    if (empty(session()->get('auth')) || session()->get('auth') == FALSE)
    {
      //However you would destroy your session
      session()->destroy();
      //Check if the request is in fact an AJAX call
      return $request->isAjax() ? 
        //Yes, return a special code that the AJAX call is looking for 
        Services::response()->setStatusCode(401) :
        //Else redirect to whatever named route your login page uses
        redirect()->route('login');  
    }

  }
```